# How to rotate a LaTeX ylabel in gnuplot?

Tags: graphics, gnuplot

I would like the `ylabel` on a gnuplot to be the same as `$\omega_2(R_{3,n})$` appears in LaTeX.  But if I use the following, it overlaps with the plot itself.

```
set ylabel "\\omega_2(R_{3,n})"
```

One way to get around this problem is to rotate the ylabel by `90` degrees.  How can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following ([source](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/label3-e.html)):

```
gnuplot> set lmargin 20
gnuplot> set label 1 '\omega_2(R_{3,n})' at graph -0.2, graph 0.5
```

Somewhat unrelated here, but don't you need to use write `$\omega_2(R_{3,n})$` when trying to produce LaTeX-output with gnuplot?